# Possible to extract title and pagenum of each page in a pdf file

Tags: text-processing, pdf

I was wondering if there are some ways to extract title and pagenum of each page in a pdf file? Either by some applications, or by programming in some programming language with some pdf libraries?

The title of each page is supposed to be the first line of the page, for example, in slides/presentation files.

The output is supposed to be a text file, with following format:

```
title_of_first_page pagenum_of_first_page
title_of_second_page pagenum_of_second_page
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following script will print the first line of each page of the PDF file passed as argument, followed by a space and the line number... It uses tools from [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) (package `poppler-utils` on Debian or Ubuntu).

```
#!/bin/bash
if="$1"
pages=$(pdfinfo "$if" | sed -nre 's/^Pages: +([0-9]+)$/\1/p')
for ((i=1; i<=$pages; i++)) ;do
    printf "%s %d\n" "$(pdftotext -f $i -l $i -layout "$if" - | head -n 1)" $i
done
```

Comment: Thanks! What does "psuedo" mean?

Comment: If a page's title has one or two lines, is that possible to be detectable? Note that the pdf file is generated from presentation formats, such as powerpoint.

Comment: Here [psuedo](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pseudo;jsessionid=0F2F620E40B61F6726311899C8B91352) doesn't specifically refer to psuedo-code. I used it in a normal (English) sense. I just meant that it's not the actual command-line arg, but it will serve the same purpose...  About the multi-line header: I've just now looked at PowerPoint presentation which I converted to a PDF. The first line filtered by the above script is the first line of the first text field of any given page. The `pdftotext` method doesn't have any way of knowing if the originating field contains a newline.

Comment: It's spelled *pseudo*, and I took the liberty of removing that part anyway as it was confusing even when spelled correctly.