# Possible to extract title and pagenum of each page in a djvu file

Tags: text-processing, djvu

This is a djvu version of [the questions I asked before for pdf files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20408/possible-to-extract-title-and-pagenum-of-each-page-in-a-pdf-file).
I have tried a similar idea as [fred has given to the previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20408/possible-to-extract-title-and-pagenum-of-each-page-in-a-pdf-file/20427#20427). But I am now stuck at how to get the number of pages of a djvu file, because I don't know which command can be used for that purpose.

For the sake of completion, I now just rephrase the question here:

I was wondering if there are some ways to extract title and pagenum of each page in a djvu file? Either by some applications, or by programming in some programming language with some djvu libraries?

The title of each page is supposed to be the first line of the page, for example, in slides/presentation files.

The output is supposed to be a text file, with following format:

```
title_of_first_page pagenum_of_first_page
title_of_second_page pagenum_of_second_page
...
```

Thanks and regards!

Comment: `evince --page-label=1` (where '1' is page number 1) displays the page, but I don't have any .djvu files which contain text, do I can't test it any further...

Comment: @fred: Thanks! An example with text http://download1336.mediafire.com/cy2gv2hc7qkg/5860xlbkw3asvk1/The+Geometry+of+Exponential+Families.djvu

Comment: I mis-judged `page-label`. It opens a djvu document for preview at the specified page... (I'm still looking at the issue with the document you provided)

Comment: @fred: I am mostly using djview to view djvu files. I suspect the program I am looking for may be based on djvulibre, such as djvused, djvm, etc. But I cannot find the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the [.pdf example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20408/possible-to-extract-title-and-pagenum-of-each-page-in-a-pdf-file), the following script will print the first line of text found on a given page (via `head -n 1`).
 You can see the available commands by typing `djvused --help` in the terminal.

`djvused` is in the package `djvulibre-bin`

```
if="$HOME/Downloads/The Geometry of Exponential Families.djvu"
pages=$(djvused -e 'n' "$if")
for ((i=1; i<=$pages; i++)) ;do
    printf "%s %d\n" "$(djvused -e 'select '$i'; print-pure-txt' "$if" | head -n 1)" $i
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if `djvused -e 'select pagenum; print-pure-txt' djvufile` can only convert a single page into text, i.e. can djvused convert several pages by one call to the command?