# Split pdf document based on section

Tags: command-line, pdf

(*This may be a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), more on the context at the end*)

Is there any way of programmatically splitting a pdf based on the section titles? That is

> from this pdf, produce 2 pdfs, where one contains everything up to the section called "XY", and the second contains all the rest.

I [know how to split a pdf based on the page number](https://superuser.com/questions/345086/split-pdf-document-from-command-line-in-linux), but is there anything more "semantical" available?

(In short, the original problem: the NSF wants to have the list of references in one document, and the description in another, and since I use LaTeX / pandoc to produce my document, it's simpler to just have everything in 1 document and then split it. Links don't matter, obviously.)

Comment: I guess maybe this tool https://github.com/HeimMatthias/pdfpagelabels combined with some of the answers at https://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf could help.

Comment: Or maybe using https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20427/101324  . Mmmm, I may be up to something with that.

Comment: You could use, e.g., `\section{Section to Split At}\wlog{SPLITSECTION STARTS AT PAGE \thepage}` to write the page number to the LaTeX log file, then grep the LaTeX log file for that line to get the page number and split it there. (Or there are similar solutions using lualatex.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stewart's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/739422/101324) gave me pretty much all the tools, but I made two important edits to their solution:

1. Use [coherent pdf](https://community.coherentpdf.com/) to preserve the table of content (pdftk just delete it),
2. Make the command split the file in two, instead of splitting the file into as many files as chapters.

Re-using the `parser.awk` shared by Stewarts, assuming that the source is called `source.pdf` and that the chapter we want to use to split the document is called "Appendix", this gives:

```
pdftk source.pdf dump_data | \
awk -f parser.awk  | \
grep Appendix | \
{ 
    IFS=";" ; \
    read -r title start end; \
    ./cpdf source.pdf  1-"`expr $start - 1`" -o A.pdf; \
    ./cpdf source.pdf "$start"-"$end" -o B.pdf;
}
```

This

1. Dump the metadata of the file,
2. Extract the relevant bits (`title ; page start ; page ends`),
3. Grab the relevant bit for the Appendix,
4. Set the separator for `read` to be `;`
5. Store the title in a `title` variable, and the start page in `start` and end page in `end`,
6. output all the pages from 1 to `start - 1` (which corresponds to the page before the appendix begins) into a file called `A.pdf`,
7. output the rest of the document into a file called `B.pdf`.

Answer (score 2):

I like using `pdftk` for this type of work.

If I create a basic document using Latex, it might look like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext} % For lorem ipsum text
\usepackage{hyperref} % Turns chapters/sections into bookmarks

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\Blindtext[10]

\section{Subsection of chapter 1}
\Blindtext[3]

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\Blindtext[20]

\chapter{Third Chapter}
\Blindtext

\pdfbookmark{Example bookmark}{A}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

When I run this through `pdflatex`, it generates an 13-page PDF with automatic bookmarks for each chapter, a deep bookmark for section 1.1,  a manual bookmark later, and lots of lorem ipsum paragraphs.

Now that we have a pdf, we can use `pdftk` to get some insights about it. There's lots of data, so I reduced it down to the interesting section.

```
$ pdftk sample.pdf dump_data
InfoBegin
...
NumberOfPages: 13
BookmarkBegin
BookmarkTitle: First Chapter
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 1
BookmarkBegin
BookmarkTitle: Subsection of chapter 1
BookmarkLevel: 2
BookmarkPageNumber: 3
BookmarkBegin
BookmarkTitle: Second Chapter
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 5
BookmarkBegin
BookmarkTitle: Third Chapter
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 11
BookmarkBegin
BookmarkTitle: Example bookmark
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 12
PageMediaBegin
...
```

When we hit a `BookmarkBegin` tag, we know we have a bookmark.  When we see `BookmarkTitle: X` we know that we have reached section `X`.  There is a `BookmarkPageNumber:`  associated with each bookmark.  You can use that for your split. You could also use the `BookmarkLevel` to filter the level (chapter, section, subsection) you want your splits.

---

Let's say you wanted to split between Chapters 1 and 2.  We can see from the data, that we need to add a split before page 4:

```
BookmarkTitle: Second Chapter
BookmarkPageNumber: 5
```

Now that we have our page number, we can use `pdftk` to do the split.  This actually involves using `cat` on specific pages:

```
pdftk sample.pdf cat 1-4 output sample-1.pdf
pdftk sample.pdf cat 5-end output sample-2.pdf
```

---

Let's go for a more generic approach and script this for a pdf called `sample.pdf`.  Let's split the PDF at each high-level bookmark (filtering out the section).

First, let's translate the bookmark tags into an easier-to-parse format, we could write something in `awk` (I'm going to save this as `parser.awk`)

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS=": "
    OFS=";"
}
/^BookmarkBegin/ {
  if (this_level > 1) { # Only handle high-level sections
    next
  }
  if (this_page == "" || this_title == ""){
    next
  }
  if (last_page != "" && last_title != "") {
    print last_title, last_page, this_page-1
  }
  last_title=this_title
  last_page=this_page
  this_title=this_page=this_level=""
}
/^BookmarkTitle:/ {
    this_title=$2
}
/^BookmarkPageNumber:/ {
    this_page=$2
}
/^BookmarkLevel:/ {
    this_level=$2
}
END {
  print last_title, last_page, this_page-1
  print this_title, this_page, "end"
}
```

Here, I'm assuming that titles will not include a `;`, so I'm using that as the output delimiter.  This script outputs:

1. the name of each section
2. First page of the section
3. Last page of the section.

```
$ pdftk sample.pdf dump_data | awk -f parser.awk
First Chapter;1;4
Second Chapter;5;10
Third Chapter;11;11
Example bookmark;12;end
```

Now let's iterate over each line and call `pdftk` with that in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
                                                                                
sequence=1                                                                      
                                                                                
pdftk sample.pdf dump_data | awk -f parser.awk | \                              
while IFS=";" \                                                                 
read -r title start end                                                         
do                                                                              
  pdftk sample.pdf cat "$start"-"$end" output sample-$sequence-"$title".pdf      
  sequence=$((sequence+1))                                                      
done
```

This leaves you with the following:

```
$ ls *.pdf
'sample-1-First Chapter.pdf'
'sample-2-Second Chapter.pdf'
'sample-3-Third Chapter.pdf'
'sample-4-Example bookmark.pdf'
sample.pdf
```

One limitation of this is that when there are several bookmarks on the same page or there are very few bookmarks, it gets a bit confused.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am using pftk as well to split the file, and the way you identify the page number where the splits needs to occur is ingenious. I would have to try and write a macro that does all the work for me, but I'll see if I'll manage.

Comment: I updated the post to include a script that does the work for you.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had used python libraries `py_pdf_parser` and `pdfplumber` to achieve something similar last year. On top of that, I used MathPix API (which is paid but minimal fees) to do final conversion to latex.

You can checkout my script here and see if it helps: https://github.com/sekerez/linear_algebra_done_right/blob/main/problems/extract_problems_from_pdf_book.py This script extracted all the problems in the book and neatly organized them in a data-structure based on the exercise number and problem number. It was amazing that this was actually possible using a few lines of code.

You'd have to adapt the script it to your use case. PDFs are very unwieldy to be processed by the machine since each PDF is very different. Hence, you'd need to handcraft your own script based on your PDF formatting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your solution. It seems very ingenious and well suited for your use, but it is a bit of an overkill for simply splitting a pdf in two, in my opinion.